# Text Rotation in Cairo

Tags: graphics, cairo

I want to rotate text in Cairo, for that I am using a function : `cairo_rotate(m_cr, angle)`, to rotate by angle radians. Now to unset the angle to start normal text rendering, should I call `cairo_rotate(m_cr, - angle) function or cairo_rotate(m_cr, 0.0)`, I mean is the rotation in cairo cumulative ?

Answer (score 3):

Rotation (and all other transformations) are cumulative.

However, IMHO it's nicer to use `cairo_save(cr); cairo_rotate(cr, angle);` and later `cairo_restore(cr);` to undo the effect. This will also work correctly for other kind of transformations, resets the current clip and the current source. In fact, `cairo_restore` restores everything but the current path.